# Reorder GET variables

Tags: php, methods, get

I have one question, how can I reoder the GET variables.. it is very complicate to explain, but i think is much better to show the code.

```
http://URL.com/?product_id=23&year=2013&seite=reporting&action=jahres&report=jahres
```

but i really want is like this.

```
http://URL.com/?seite=reporting&action=jahres&report=jahres&product_id=23&year=2013



<input type="hidden" name="seite" value="reporting"/>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="jahres"/>
<input type="hidden" name="report" value="jahres"/>
```

the action of the form is just the URL of the page.

The GET variable ?seite=reporting, <--- this i need to be always on the front from all the others variables, how could i do?

Thank for you help!

Comment: Does the order really matter? (FYI, the answer is no)

Comment: is more for stetic you know, i just wanted to know if it is possible to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Hidden inputs you can order the view of these variables in your URL, reording the position of these variables, for example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="seite" value="reporting"/>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="jahres"/>
<input type="hidden" name="report" value="jahres"/>
```

**You can do like this:**

```
<form>
 1. First Level in your form
<input type="hidden" name="seite" value="reporting"/>

2. Last level in your form the other variables hidden or not.
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="jahres"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="report" value="jahres"/>
</form>
```

**If you want to access to the variables:**

```
$seite = isset($_GET['seite']) ? $_GET['seite'] : null;
```

And when you press the submit  button the form will put the first input hidden, GET in your URL, but really doens't matter, is just for stetic!

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing them in the url yourself, it does not matter what order you place them.

It does not matter. You can add more query string parameters, or remove them in any order. Then access them using `$_GET["product_id"]` etc and handle accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

`GET` variables aren't ordered, you can place them in any order you would like and it would still give the same results.

Answer (score 0):

You could put your GET Variables in an array

```
$variables = Array (
[0] => $_GET['one']
[1] => $_GET['two']
[2] => $_GET['three']
);
```

then just echo them out one by one in URL output

`$url = "http://website.com/script.php?get1=" . $variables[0] . "&get2=" . $variables[1];`